# C# system.timers.timer weird behavior

Tags: c#, algorithm, timer, system.timers.timer

I am trying to implement Bully Coordinator election algorithm. In this algorithm, Coordinator sends the alive message every 10 seconds and all the processes wait for at least 14 seconds to receive alive, if they don't receive the message within that time, they will initiate dead coordinator election.

The problem is AliveTimer (Timer3_Count) is increasing exponentially and active processes are also affecting it. I don't know why it is behaving weirdly.

When the initial coordinator is sending the Alive message then counter works perfectly but after dead coordinator election, it behaves weirdly.

```
else if (Received_Text.Contains("Alive:"))
            {
                SetText(Received_Text + "\n");
                Coordinator_Alive = true;

                Timer3_Counter = 0;

                if (Alive_Count == 0)
                {
                    Alive_Count++;


                    AliveTimer.Interval = (1 * 1000);
                    AliveTimer.Enabled = true;
                    AliveTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(AliveTimer_Elapsed);
                    AliveTimer.Start();

                }

            }
```

The elapsed function is here
I think there is something wrong with my program, I tried everything.

```
private void AliveTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer3_Counter++;
        SetTimer(Timer3_Counter.ToString());

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int rand_time = rnd.Next(14, 18);

        if (Timer3_Counter == 14)
        {
            AliveTimer.Stop();

            Timer3_Counter = 0;
            Alive_Count = 0;

            if (Coordinator_Alive == false)
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Dead Coordinator Election: " + txName.Text);
                _clientSocket.Send(buffer);

                Timer4_Counter = 0;

                DeadTimer.Interval = (1 * 1000);
                DeadTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(DeadTimer_Elapsed);
                DeadTimer.Enabled = true;
                DeadTimer.Start();

            }

        }

        if (Coordinator_Alive == true)
            Coordinator_Alive = false;

    }
```

and the dead Coordinator election code is here

```
else if (Received_Text.Contains("Dead Coordinator Election:"))
            {
                SetCPID("");
                Coordinator_Alive = false;
                Alive_Count = 0;
                Timer3_Counter = 0;

                AliveTimer.Stop();
                AliveTimer.Enabled = false;


                string output = Regex.Match(Received_Text, @"\d+").Value;
                SetText("Dead Coordinator Election Received from Process ID: " + output + "\n");

                if (Convert.ToInt32(txName.Text) > Convert.ToInt32(output))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Greater Process No: " + txName.Text + " found than " + output + "\n");
                    _clientSocket.Send(buffer);
                    SetText("Our Process No: " + txName.Text + " is Greater than " + output + "\n");
                    Lower_Count++;

                    byte[] buffer1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Dead Coordinator Election: " + txName.Text);
                    _clientSocket.Send(buffer1);
                }
                else
                {
                    byte[] Txt_Send = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Our Process No: " + txName.Text + " is less than " + output);
                    _clientSocket.Send(Txt_Send);
                    Greater_Count++;
                }

            }
```

The full code can be found here
[Bully Algorithm](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B80iCC4NJjPLX1JNbUtPZXJIaTQ)

Note: I am using passive server just to broadcast messages from each process

Comment: _The problem is AliveTimer (Timer3_Count) is increasing exponentially and active processes are also affecting it. I don't know why it is behaving weirdly._  You are almost certainly wiring up the `Elapsed()` handler multiple times.  This will result in your code being run multiple times for each "tick". You should only be wiring up that handler **once**, usually when you create it.

Comment: it started ticking multiple times when I stop and again start the timer.
How to avoid this?

Comment: ...and how are you stopping and starting the timer?  Show us that code please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes the problem, but I think **you** will be able to figure the cause quickly if you **log** start and stop all all methods and analyse the output.

This would help establish if: 
1. As @Idle_Mind suggested, that you are adding more and more handlers
2. The time taken to execute each method creeps up
and more...

I don't know how you app is built but you can even start with `Console.WriteLine` or `Debug.WriteLine`.